# How can I search through xml using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, search, nullreferenceexception

I want to search through my xml file. The structure looks like this:

```
<AForetag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Place ID="1006">
        <Foretag>
            <Epost>info@abc123.se</Epost>
            <Namn>Abe</Namn>
            <Ort>Abc123</Ort>
            <Adress>Abc123</Adress>
            <Postnummer>Abc123</Postnummer>
            <Landskap>Abc123</Landskap>
            <Telefon>Abc123</Telefon>
            <Medlemskap>Abc123</Medlemskap>
        </Foretag>
        <Foretag>
            <Epost>def456</Epost>
            <Namn>def456</Namn>
            <Ort>def456</Ort>
            <Adress>def456</Adress>
            <Postnummer>def456</Postnummer>
            <Landskap>def456</Landskap>
            <Telefon>def456</Telefon>
            <Medlemskap>def456</Medlemskap>
        </Foretag>
    </Place>
</Aforetag>
```

And I want to search for the Element `<Landskap>`. And if I get and match I should pick all the other elements, Epost, Namn, Ort, Adress, Postnummer, Landskap, Telefon and Medlemskap. The info I want to put in an array.

I have tried this:

```
var aforetag = from foretag in doc.Descendants("Place")
                       where foretag.Attribute("ID").Value == "1006"
                       select foretag;


var landskap = aforetag.Elements("Foretag")
                       .Descendants()
                       .Where(x => x.Element("Landskap")
                       .Value
                       .Contains(s)
                       .Descendants()
                       .Select(c => (string)c)
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: You tried that. And, what happened?

Comment: Ill get this Warning: NullReferenceException was unhandled.
Objectreferens has not been given an instance of an object. (Sorry for bad translate)

And its stops to work.

Comment: So, you also don't know what an exception is. Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks, its my XML schema thats was messed up. Had some bad values in it like '--'.

Comment: @faceplant your query is not good, I doubt it doesn't work as you expected unless you have had some modification to make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
var landskap = aforetag.Elements("Foretag")
                       .Where(e=>e.Element("Landskap").Value.Contains(s))
                       .Select(e=>e.Elements().Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray());
//the result is an IEnumerable<string[]> for the matched keyword s
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not well formed. Copy this into VS and there are a few errors, fix one and more errors!...

And most importantly, your XML is not XML as the start and end tag don't even match! Plus, there are other issues.

Fix all these and I'm sure it will help.

Comment: It did help, sorry for wasting your guys time.

Comment: @faceplant No worries!